# How to have TextBlocks with same scale?

Tags: wpf, resize, scale, textblock

I have a problem trying to adjust the size of TextBlocks. I have a grid with 3 columns and 6 rows, in the second column I have a TextBlock in each row, each TextBlock text has different length so when I resize the window some texts looks larger or smaller than the others.

Is there a way to have the same scale in each TextBlock when I resize the window? I would like all the TextBlock look the same size when I resize the window.

This is the code I have:

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="Some long text 12345" FontSize="20" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="Some longer text 1234567890" FontSize="20" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt3" Text="Text3" FontSize="20" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt4" Text="Text4" FontSize="20" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt5" Text="Text5" FontSize="20" />
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt6" Text="Text6" FontSize="20" />
    </Viewbox>
```

Thanks in advance,

Alberto

Comment: You should not scale text at all when the window size changes. Choose an appropriate font size (like 20 as you did already) and remove all the Viewboxes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the TextBlock directly in the gird, no need of viewBox
2. Set  instead of *
3. There is one more option you can set in ColumnDefination or RowDefination "SharedSizeGroup"
   the rows or columns with same name will share the same height or width